# Reputation history tooltip for suggested edits has pulled an rchern (it's backwards)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

Since we're nearing the end of the month and I need to fill up my pedantic bug quota, I noticed while taking a look at [someone's reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson?tab=reputation) that the tooltip for suggested edit approval reputation bonuses was coming at the event from the wrong end:

[image: incorrect tooltip description for suggested edit]

The user didn't receive reputation because they *approved a suggested edit*, but rather because they *had a suggested edit approved*. In the case of answers, the text is "answer was upvoted," so the expected text for suggested edit bonuses would be "suggested edit was approved."

Comment: Isn't an rchern (: so is it backward backwards? `backward(backwards(":)"))`

Comment: oy?​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Indeed @BoltClock'saUnicorn, indeed.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff [*hides*](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/880508#880508)

Comment: http://BackwardSmile.info/ anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah-hah, an rchern bug you say?  Well - that must be fixed (:  It will be in the next deploy.

Now if only somebody would write a script to fix all of those smileys.